# Data in Components Spark in a ItemRenderer in Flex

Tags: list, apache-flex, slideshow, itemrenderer

I need to create a slideshow using data received from another view.

I'm calling the slideshow's view like this:

```
<s:List id = "list" dataProvider = "{actions}"
change = "navigator.pushView (DetailsProduct, list.selectedItem) ">
<s:itemRenderer>
<fx:Component>
<s:MobileIconItemRenderer
labelField = "title"
messageField = "description"
decoratorClass = "{data.icon}">
</s:MobileIconItemRenderer>
</fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

I think the problem is the time to send the parameter because I'm passing the selected item and must pass the entire list.

And the other problem is in the view, I can see the object received outside the list but not inside it.

With this code the object appears, but the back and forward buttons doesn't work.

```
<s:List id = "myList"
     dataProvider = "{actions}">
</s:List>

<s:Image source="{data.icon}"/>
<s:Label text="{data.title}"/>
<s:Label text="{data.description}"/>

<s:HGroup>
<s:Button label="Forward" click="imgForward(event)"/>
<s:Button label="Back" click="imgBack(event)"/>
</s:hgroup>
```

And this code shows nothing, even the object being called the same way.

```
<s:List id = "myList"
     dataProvider = "{actions}">
         <s:itemRenderer>
     <fx:Component>
     <s:ItemRenderer>
         <s:Image source="{data.icon}"/>
         <s:Label text="{data.title}"/>
         <s:Label text="{data.description}"/>
     </s:ItemRenderer>
     </fx:Component>
     </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>

<s:HGroup>
     <s:Button label="Forward" click="imgForward(event)"/>
     <s:Button label="Back" click="imgBack(event)"/>
</s:hgroup>
```

Comment: For future reference; the button in the editor with "curly brackets" will format code for easy display; so you don't have to put spaces in the tag names.

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  The [data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IDataRenderer.html#data) property is defined in the [IDataRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IDataRenderer.html) interface.

When a component is used as a renderer, the data element that the instance of component represents is passed into the renderer using the data property.

You didn't quantify what "works or "not works" mean, so I'm not sure what your desired behavior is, nor why one is wrong, and one isn't.  In your first sample, I would not expect a data property to have any value:

```
<s:List id="myList"
    creationComplete="criaLista(event)"
    dataProvider="{actions}">
</s:List>

<s:Image source="{data.icon}"/>
<s:Label text="{data.title}"/>
<s:Label text="{data.description}"/>
```

I'm not sure what the dataProvider contains, but if it contains objects, I would expect something to be displayed in the list.  I would expect the Image, and the labels to display no visual elements, because the data property is most likely null.  If you wanted to reference the item selected in the list, instead of accessing data, you could access something like this:

```
<s:Image source="{myList.selectedItem.icon}"/>
<s:Label text="{myList.selectedItem.title}"/>
<s:Label text="{myList.selectedItem.description}"/>
```

It uses the selectedItem property from the list instance to modify the display elements.

In your second sample, where you do create an itemRenderer, I would expect it to work:

```
<s:List id="myList"
    creationComplete="criaLista(event)"
    dataProvider="{actions}">
        <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
    <s:ItemRenderer>
        <s:Image source="{data.icon}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.title}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.description}"/>
    </s:ItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

However, the itemRenderer does nothing to position the image or two labels, so I would expect them to be layered on top of each other, which is probably not desirable behavior.  You can set the X and Y values to size them.

If you want to elaborate on the specific problems; why your first sample 'works' and the second doesn't, please do.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com +1, nice cover. @Leticia there's a conflict in naming variable "data", it's a problem to understand, what are you trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. What I'm trying to do is:
I have a list with several items. When I click on it to show a slideshow with the details of that item where I can go to the details of the next item, or to return the item details above.
In the first code I can view these details, but they aren't in the list, so I can't go into the details of the next section or back to the item details above.
In the second code, I try to show the item in a list, but nothing appears.
I don't know how it pulls the references when is off the list and can't does the same when it is inside.

Comment: @Leticia Give us a full runnable sample; so we can take the code and try to run it.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com How I can send it for you? Sorry about my explanation, I don't speak English very well.

Comment: @Leticia Edit your original question and post the code, plus related files.  Alternately (if your code compiles) you could publish a release build w/ source from Flash Builder and post that somewhere; then edit your original post to include a link to that project.